# Objective-C APN Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have both certificates created and the APP in the portal has APNS enabled for both development and production.

In development it works fine, but in production when someone downloads the app and signs in my server is updated with **NAPN** which stands for **No Push Notifications**.

This is the section of code it goes to if the user has them disabled, but I have checked with multiple users and they are completely enabled but for some reason its like it is stuck with the development APNS certificate or something, also users are not prompted to enable push notifications when they first download and launch the app.

I don't know if I need to approach apple with this questions but if anyone can, please assist with recommendations on how to get this to work that would be greatly appreciated.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //Clear notifications upon launching
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    //Register with APN
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != 0)
    {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }else
    {
    URLSingleton *registrar = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
    [registrar setDevToken:@"NAPN"];

    //Register APN with iShame Service
    URLSingleton *urls = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
    NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"user\":\"%@\",\"token\":\"%@\"}", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"session_token"], [registrar getDevToken]];
    NSData *authData = [authString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSMutableURLRequest *url = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urls.updateAuth]];

    [url setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [url setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [url setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [url setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
    [url setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [authData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [url setHTTPBody:authData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:url delegate:self];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [connection start];

    } 
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post your code for push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always register for remote notification types, since that call is what causes the user to be prompted to enable push notifications on the first time they launch the app .  Remove that condition.  I don't know how this code worked in the sandbox env. My guess is that you added this condition at a later stage,  after you already ran your app without the condition,  and that's how the registration worked in that env.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the .ipa, instead of building with the distribution, (unless you're putting it on the store) build with the developer license, so that the app will sign it with your signature. I have had issues with apps and that was my problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is for the app store.  It worked when I built with developer license and tested locally with my iPhone but then I submitted it to apple and changed to build with Distribution and that is where it is failing to do push notifications.

Comment: Basically anyone that downloads by app from the store doesn't get prompted to enable push notifications, under the notifications it shows that they are setup to receive them for my app, but the code path that always comes back is that no notifications are enabled on the device.

Comment: Have you made sure to go under ItunesConnect and add the push notifications into the app, or alternatively through Application Launcher?

Comment: I am on itunes connect and I don't see where I select push notifications.  Can you provide a screenshot of exactly where you are looking?  The place I did it on was the provisioning profile.

Comment: My apologies for that, I was confused. I thought it was on Itunes Connect. For your issue, where exactly did you put the code for the prompt when the user is supposed to be prompted, and could you tell me the name and if it is free or not

Comment: It is a free app called iShame.
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != 0)
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}else
{
        URLSingleton *registrar = [URLSingleton sharedInstance];
        [registrar setDevToken:@"NAPN"];
}

Comment: It always hits the else statement because it says no push notifications are enabled

Comment: Where do i go to know if the push notifications are enabled or not?

Comment: Sorry about the extended questions, i'm just trying to gather all the info begore giving you an answer.

Comment: Well you can go to your notification center and see if they are.  I can check the database and tell you if you have a apn_token or not.

Comment: If you are user abowman the app does not have push notifications enabled for you.

Comment: yes, thats me. It seems as if you are trying to say that the badgeNumber is 0, and then in your if statement you said != 0, therefore causing it to skip to your else statement because it already starts out at 0......so I would say maybe change that to >= 0, and see what that does

Comment: This works when I use the development/sandbox push notifications, just when I went to the app store with it did push notifications no longer work.

Comment: Also this check [UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != 0 is just checking which notifications I have enabled, the setting of the badge number removes the number on the icon on the home screen of the iOS device.

Comment: well I'm not sure how to go from this point on, but you can contact apple from this <https://developer.apple.com/notifications/> I am sorry if I was more of a burden than a help, but sometimes things just take a bit to figure out ya know? :) God bless you!

Comment: Thanks, that link helps more than you know.

Comment: No problem! :) I hope you figure out the issue with your app! Apps with constant issues are the absoulte worst, and the harddest things to figure out, and it's good to know where to lead people when you cant help :)